# express-validator: how to check queries

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

With `express-validator` how can we check the query for a request?

In the documentation there is an example to check body:

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

app.post('/user', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

How can I set it to check only the query for `GET` methods?

`GET /user?username=name`
I just want to check `username` in the query here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by:

```
app.post('/user', [
  check.query('username')
], (req, res) => {
 //your code
});
```

Answer (score 21):

To check for variables in query params, i.e., req.query, use **query([fields, message])**.
Same as **check([fields, message])**, but only checking **req.query**.

### Example:

**Installing express-validator**

```
npm install --save express-validator
```

**Importing query**

```
const { query } = require('express-validator/check');
```

**Using query**

```
router.post('/add-product', 
                isAuth, 
                [
                    query('title')
                        .isString().withMessage('Only letters and digits allowed in title.')
                        .trim()
                        .isLength({min: 3}).withMessage('Title too short. Enter a longer title!'),
                    query('price', 'Enter a valid price.')
                        .isFloat(),
                    query('description')
                        .trim()
                        .isLength({min: 30, max: 600}).withMessage('Description must be of minimum 30 and maximum 600 characters!'),
                ],
                adminController.postAddProduct);
```

See official documentation here: https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html

Answer (score 1):

Validator is -

```
const {
    check,
    validationResult
} = require('express-validator');

const fetchStatementValidator = [
    check('startdate').not().isEmpty().withMessage("Start date cannot be empty"),
    check('enddate').not().isEmpty().withMessage("End Date cannot be empty"),
]

module.exports.fetchStatementValidator = fetchStatementValidator;
```

Api is -

```
router.get("/fetchStatement", auth.adminAuth, validator.fetchStatementValidator, utility.statements.fetchStatement); //fetch statement
```

API Definition -

```
/* Fetch transections */
module.exports.fetchStatement = async (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            success: false,
            errors: errors.array()
        });
    }
};
```

Api Hit via Postman -

```
http://localhost:5000/loans/fetchCompletedLoans?page=1&startdate=2019-09-08&enddate=
```

Response -

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "value": "",
            "msg": "End Date cannot be empty",
            "param": "enddate",
            "location": "query"
        }
    ]
}
```